# Issue with linked servers...absolute novice

Tags: linked-server

I've got 2 instances on the same sql server that someone needs to be able to run a query to compare data.  His original error with the query was regarding sys.servers and it not being able to find it.  I've created a link to the other instance within linked servers in management studio and the tables can be listed and rows viewed from there.

Main issue arises, again, when the query is written out where if I go select from [, I dont get a list of the tables in the database that I've linked to, even though its working from management studio.

Am I missing something really stupid here?

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the full query?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply I have managed to get this working now.  Was a little bit stumped as it wasnt giving me the tables when I was doing a [ but it obviously doesnt for linked dbs.  Ended up typing it all and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was being a bit over enthusiastic in what SQL would show me with a linked database.  It didnt give me the drop down showing the tables in the linked db when I hit [ so typing it all out worked.